# Selenium ChromeDriver hide on server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, .net-7.0

I've a .net 7.0 webapi that call my dll library that use Selenium.Webdriver to navigate the web.

On my local pc with VS2022 on win10 all work fine in debug and release mode, but when I publish the solution and go on my server with Windows Server 2016 all work almost-fine: I know chrome navigates cause I can see it in Task Manager but I cannot see Chrome (I'm not going in headless mode, I need to see the navigation).

It seems like on server there is some kind of protection.
Is there any configuration or flag or other to set on server to show Chrome?

Thanks to all in advance.

UPDATE: same behaviour with other library/driver too, i.e. Playwright.
Someone can give me an opinion?